# "[Bleep] talking" What's the offensive word that was bleeped out?

Tags: offensive-language

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWvDVDHJxhI), Dwayne Johnson appeared on The Tonight Show and was talking about himself being named the sexiest man alive on the cover of People Magazine.

This conversation starts at [12 seconds into the video](https://youtu.be/CWvDVDHJxhI?t=12s):

> **Jimmy Fallon:** How much grief are you getting for being on the cover of the sexiest man alive?
>
> **Dwayne Johnson:** I mean, first of all, it's an honor. It's really, really cool, right, but, yeah, I am getting so much grief especially from my boys. Of course, as you can imagine, right, everybody's just...It's just a continuation of just -- What's that term? -- Oh, [bleep] talking.

Of course, you can't hear the bleeped word, but can you guess what the word was in context? I think it might be helpful to view the video from 12 seconds.

Comment: He is saying "shit-talking" ... talking shit. Meaning ribbing, kidding, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about censorship of an entertainment program on TV, and not about learning English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think he says **shit talking**. A similar British term would be **talk rubbish**. Shit talking basically means useless talk. This expression doesn't have a set in stone meaning. What it exactly means really depends on the context.

Example:

> Donald Trump talks about how he's going to build that wall to separate America from Mexican illegal migrants. I think he just **talks too much shit**! Come on, it's the 21st century, for Christ's sake! That stupid wall is not going to solve any of our social and political problems.

Comment: "Shit talking" usually comes with the connotation of either bragging or making fun of, the sort of talk people might have about their respective sports teams, or the outcome of some other personal contest between them; when between friends the implication is almost always that it is friendly at heart but can sometimes get nasty: bar fights can certainly begin over shit talking.

Answer (score 3):

He says "shit talking". I think he means that his friends and family are playfully making fun of him. It's a variation of [trash talking](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trash%20talk)

Answer (score 3):

The phrase he used is probably

> [shit talking](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shit%20talking)
>
> Shit talking occurs when people have too much free time (see: not having a life) and make up rumors or put down others, whether they are enemies, friends, or just random people.